# Combine two time-series with tz-aware datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timezone

I have two `time-series` below. `df1` has an index in a DateTime format which includes `date` and `hour` without minute and second. `df2` has a full datetime index, also in a DateTime format. In the full data, df1 is much shorter than df2 in terms of the number of rows. `Datetime` index of the two `df` are timezone (tz) aware.

As you can see, the time of both datasets span from 4am to the 8am. `df1`, however, skips some hours, while in `df2`, all hours are available. Note: in this example, only odd hours are skipped, but it is not the case in the full data.

**df1**

```
    value1
date            
2016-04-01 04:00:00+07:00  16
2016-04-01 06:00:00+07:00  76
2016-04-01 08:00:00+07:00  23
```

**df2**

```
    value2
DateTime    
2016-04-01 04:00:00+07:00 257.96
2016-04-01 04:15:00+07:00 317.58
2016-04-01 04:30:00+07:00 333.39
2016-04-01 04:45:00+07:00 333.39
2016-04-01 05:00:00+07:00 449.96
2016-04-01 05:15:00+07:00 466.42
2016-04-01 05:30:00+07:00 498.56
2016-04-01 05:45:00+07:00 454.73
2016-04-01 06:00:00+07:00 472.45
2016-04-01 06:15:00+07:00 489.85
2016-04-01 06:30:00+07:00 169.54
2016-04-01 06:45:00+07:00 276.13
2016-04-01 07:00:00+07:00 293.70
2016-04-01 07:15:00+07:00 108.05
2016-04-01 07:30:00+07:00 179.21
2016-04-01 07:45:00+07:00 201.80
2016-04-01 08:00:00+07:00 201.80
2016-04-01 08:15:00+07:00 201.80
2016-04-01 08:30:00+07:00 201.80
2016-04-01 08:45:00+07:00 201.80
```

I want to combine the two datasets by index. df1 should **control** which hour to be kept. The **expected** result is below.

```
    value2 value1
DateTime    
2016-04-01 04:00:00+07:00 257.96 16
2016-04-01 04:15:00+07:00 317.58 16
2016-04-01 04:30:00+07:00 333.39 16
2016-04-01 04:45:00+07:00 333.39 16
2016-04-01 06:00:00+07:00 472.45 76
2016-04-01 06:15:00+07:00 489.85 76
2016-04-01 06:30:00+07:00 169.54 76
2016-04-01 06:45:00+07:00 276.13 76
2016-04-01 08:00:00+07:00 201.80 23
2016-04-01 08:15:00+07:00 201.80 23
2016-04-01 08:30:00+07:00 201.80 23
2016-04-01 08:45:00+07:00 201.80 23
```

This is my attempt.

```
result = pd.concat([df2, df1], sort=True)
# returns no error. only combine the two df horizontally. df1 does not control the DateTime index in the result.

result = df2.merge(df1, left_index=True, right_index=True)
# returns error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can `merge` both dataframes after [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) the [`floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) of the `index` of df2, like:

```
print (df1.merge( df2.reset_index().set_index(df2.index.floor('H')), 
                  how='left', left_index=True, right_index=True).set_index('DateTime'))

                           value1  value2
DateTime                                 
2016-04-01 04:00:00+07:00      16  257.96
2016-04-01 04:15:00+07:00      16  317.58
2016-04-01 04:30:00+07:00      16  333.39
2016-04-01 04:45:00+07:00      16  333.39
2016-04-01 06:00:00+07:00      76  472.45
2016-04-01 06:15:00+07:00      76  489.85
2016-04-01 06:30:00+07:00      76  169.54
2016-04-01 06:45:00+07:00      76  276.13
2016-04-01 08:00:00+07:00      23  201.80
2016-04-01 08:15:00+07:00      23  201.80
2016-04-01 08:30:00+07:00      23  201.80
2016-04-01 08:45:00+07:00      23  201.80
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain it a bit?

Comment: @k.ko3n the idea behind floor is that it will brings back the beginning of the hour (if it was 4:15:00 then it becomes 4:00:00), so by setting the index with the date-hour at the beginning of the hour, then it becomes possible to merge with the data from df1. Then to be able to still have the data about the exact time from df2, you need to make it a column (with reset_index) before merging and once merge you can set this column back as the index. The parameter how='left' makes it such that only the time from df1 are kept. does it help?

Comment: Yes. It helped. Thanks